# Dynamics CRM language packs

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, pack

We are developing a CRM application which is deployed in multiple Latin american countries. Is there any supported or unsupported way to get multiple Spanish languages in the system, one each for language country combination (For ex: ES-AR, ES-Mx ). We have this requirement because each country has their own vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to create your own language pack, you are limited to the available ones, for example here the packs for CRM 2011:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27819

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was worried about. We might have to contact Microsoft regarding this as it is an absolute requirement for us